# Remove margins in HTML5

Tags: html, css

I can't remove the margins up, down, left and right frmo tag . What am I doing wrong?

**HTML5**
You can access to the code in these address: http://www.demo31.com/validacion/personal

**CSS**

```
    @CHARSET "utf-8";


    /* Makeshift CSS Reset */  
    *{  
        margin: 0 auto;  
        padding: 0 auto;  
    }  

    /* Tell the browser to render HTML 5 elements as block */  
    header, footer, aside, nav, article, section{  
        display: block;  
    } 

    html, body{
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 auto;
        font-family: Calibri, Verdana, Helvetica, Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
        text-align: justify;
        font-size: 66%;
        background-color: #1d293f;
        top: 0px;
        font-size-adjust: none;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-height: normal;
    }

    header, h1{
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        /*margin: -7px -1px -4px -1px;*/
        overflow: hidden; /*Remove top-margin page*/
    }

    header{
        width: 80%;
        background-color: #fbf585;
    }

    section{
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 auto;
        width: 80%;
        background-color: #ffffff;  
    }
    section > h1{
        width: 80%;
        background-color: #CCCCCC;
        border-spacing: 0px;
        font-size: 10em;        
        letter-spacing: 0.25em;
        text-align: left;
    }
```

Comment: Have you created the HTML5 elements? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/make-html5-elements-work-in-old-ie/

Comment: Yes!!! They are created.
`code`document.createElement('header');
document.createElement('nav');
document.createElement('article');
document.createElement('footer');
document.createElement('section');`code`

Have I to create tags <h1>, <ul>, etc?

Comment: You have not specified what exactly you are trying to remove, and you are not setting all margins to zero (on the contrary). Please fix the code to use 0 not 0 auto, and then explain what you see as wrong. Also consider either removing the fine print content on you demo page or making it legible.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added your html to the question as a snippet that we can work with

Answer (score 4):

Removing all margins is done `margin: 0;` ***not*** `margin: 0 auto;`

Once you define:

```
* {  
    margin: 0;  
    padding: 0; /*auto is not valid for padding*/  
}
```

You never need to set these properties again for any other element.

`*` is everything.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Also, I have lost the web centered. :(

Answer (score 2):

`auto;` doesnt work on padding, you need to set 0.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to do this

```
body{    
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to specify units when setting a value to `0`, because `0px`, `0em`, and `0hogshead` are all identical.

Comment: I'd been including units with zeros for years before someone pointed that out to me :)